# Is there an SVN UI for hosting server?

Tags: apache, linux, subversion, gui

We are considering upgrading to either a dedicated or cloud server.

What I would really like is for the hosting account to have SVN installed on it. With a UI that I can use. So when I make a change, I can create a branch on the hosting and develop on the private branch. Then when I get everything right, migrate that branch to the main site that everyone sees. And also be able to role back if I need to. I would like to have a UI in the site admin for this.

Is there a hosting service that provides this?

If it matters we were looking at rackspacecloud and we will definitely be using a LAMP (linux, apache, mysql, php) stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this isn't quite what you're looking for, but I think [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com/features/subversion) might provide that functionality. It's a hosted SVN service rather than a hosting service that provides SVN.

Answer (score 1):

Trac is fairly robust and has a large userbase. It's complex to setup (as is any SVN repo setup), however, there are some good guides out there for it. Info: http://trac.edgewall.org/ Install Instructions: http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInstall

Comment: I think by hosted, they mean something external like BitBucket, SourceForge, GitHub, etc.

Comment: Got it. Well then as an addendum, why not use (as VxJasonxV suggested) github or sourceforge? Google has their own project hosting as well.

Answer (score 1):

Any Subversion service will work for this. I use it all the time in this fashion. You don't need Subversion on your web server, just the client (TortoiseSVN is great if you are on Windows)

devZing also provides [hosted subversion](http://devzing.com/subversion)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a hosting provider whom has a utility box in place to work with the needs of a LAMP based production deployment.  The utility box can be virtual in a cloud as long as it has the same back end subnet routing to the LAMP over a private network for ease of administration and security.

Rackspace definitely has a LAMP solution although I am not for certain what developer tools and support is available. A solution plus developer kit sounds more fitting, I would recommend checking out Dev Utility Server like Logicworks, www.utility.noc.logicworks.net.

Feel free to reach out to me with any questions, best of luck.